# Como criar a tag <!DOCTYPE html> em Beautiful Soup (bs4)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Desejo criar a tag  em Beautiful Soup (bs4), e desenvolvi o seguinte:

```
from bs4 import Doctype

tag = Doctype('html')
```

Fiz o trecho acima. Mas não cria a tag .

Como proceder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Criar a Doctype com elementos beautifulsoup:

```
>>> from bs4 import Doctype
>>> tag = Doctype('html')
>>> type(tag)
<class 'bs4.element.Doctype'>
>>> print(tag)
'html'
```

Inserir em um HTML:

```
>>> from bs4 import Doctype
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

>>> html = '''<html><body></body></html>'''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

>>> tag = Doctype('html')
>>> type(tag)
<class 'bs4.element.Doctype'>
>>> tag
'html'
>>> soup.insert(0, tag)
>>> soup
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body></body></html>
```

Comment: Eu acho que ficou um pouco confuso o segundo excerto de código, onde aparentemente misturou código real e saída do programa. Creio que fazer algo similar ao que foi feito no primeiro excerto (pondo "`>>> `" antecedendo o código e nada antecedendo a saída) seja o ideal

Comment: Desculpe. fiquei sem rede não tive como editar. 
;)

Answer (score 1):

Se de fato a intenção for gerar arquivos `.html` creio que

Você pode instalar o html5lib com pip:

```
pip install html5lib
```

E depois usar o `html5lib`, assim:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('<p></p>', 'html5lib')

soup.body.append(soup.new_tag("a", href="https://pt.stackoverflow.com"))

print(soup)
```

Claro que a saída vai ser algo como:

```
b'<html>\n <head>\n </head>\n <body>\n  <p>\n  </p>\n  <a href="https://pt.stackoverflow.com">\n  </a>\n </body>\n</html>'
```

Mas para resolver bastaria concatenar uma string com o doctype do HTML5, por exemplo:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('<p></p>', 'html5lib')

soup.body.append(soup.new_tag("a", href="https://pt.stackoverflow.com"))

source = soup.prettify("utf-8")

with open("output.html", "wb") as file:
    file.write(b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n')
    file.write(source)

print(source)
```

---

Eu não conheço `html5lib` a fundo, mas talvez deva para fazer algo com isto só.

Comment: Esta alternativa é a que estou usando. Mas quero criar o objeto via bs4

Comment: @britodfbr não consigo entender a necessidade disto, exceto se fosse um doctype customizado proprio, sendo doctype nativo do HTML ele existir ou não dentro do objeto me parece irrelevante.

Comment: irei atualizar uma massa com 168k arquivos, e estou criando um script para automatizar a edição.